# Printing a string?

Tags: java, string, variables

I'm in my first programming class; can anyone help me understand why I can't print my last line please?

```
package program4;

import java.util.*;

public class Program4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, c, numComparisons;

        String comparisons = "Comparisons for triangleType determination: ";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        }
        String triangleType = "";
        System.out.print("Enter 3 positive integer lengths for the sides of a "
                + "triangle:");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextInt();
        c = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The input lengths are: a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ", and"
                + " c = " + c + "");

        if ((a + b < c) || (b + c < a) || (a + c < b)) {

            System.out.print("There is no triangle with sides " + a + ", " + b + " and "
                    + "" + c + ".");
        } else {
            numComparisons = 1;
            comparisons += "a==b";
            if (a == b) {
                comparisons += "(T)" + "(b==c)";
                numComparisons++;
                if (b == c) {
                    comparisons += "(T)";
                    triangleType = "Equilateral";
                }
            } else {
                comparisons += "(F)";
                if (a == c) {
                    comparisons += "(T)";
                    triangleType = "Isosceles";
                } else {
                    comparisons += "b==c";
                    numComparisons++;
                    comparisons += "(F)";

                    if (b == c) {
                        triangleType = "Isosceles";
                    } else {
                        comparisons += "a==c";
                        numComparisons++;
                        comparisons += "(F)";
                        triangleType = "Scalene";
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.printf("" + comparisons + (""));
            System.out.printf("numComparisons = " + numComparisons);
            System.out.println("The triangles with sides " + a + ", "
                    + " + b + ", and " + c + ", is + triangleType + ");

        }

}
```

}

Comment: search for missing '+' in your last line

Comment: Two Queries. First one - why do you think that `professor is pretty terrible`? Second one - why do you think that `only wants us to code as he code which isnt always ideal`?

Comment: One. He is pretty terrible because he tries to explain the coding techniques and what not but isnt very clear on it. Then he follows by asking if it makes sense and when you tell him it isnt clear he berates you saying such things as "This is simple and if you dont understand you should not be a computer science major." I find that pretty harsh as this is my first computer science class. Also I believe coding can be done in different innovative ways. He explicitly told us not to do our codes in any other way then the way he tells us to. I think or believe we should explore other coding options

Comment: Thanks for answering that. You are right in stating that coding can be done in different innovative ways and let nobody tell you otherwise. Hopefully, you will find coding a lot easier later on. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the words of wisdom. This professor made me want to change my major but I'll try to stick by it. I find programming so fascinating and I really dont want to give up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line syntax is pretty messed up.

this

```
 System.out.println("The triangles with sides " + a + ", "
                    + " + b + ", and " + c + ", is + triangleType + ");
```

should be

```
 System.out.println("The triangles with sides " + a + ", "
                    +  b + ", and " + c + ", is " + triangleType);
```

Comment: I got it finally. Thank you

Comment: @FarazDurrani is there a reason why?

Comment: @DwightEveridge if this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as accepted (by clicking the check mark)?

Answer (score 2):

```
 System.out.println("The triangles with sides " + a + ", "
                + " + b + ", and " + c + ", is + triangleType + ");
```

What IDE/editor are you using? It should should show you the errors here. This should be

```
System.out.println("The triangles with sides " + a + ", "
                +  b + ", and " + c + ", is" + triangleType);
```

This is better

Comment: You should try eclipse. You would then be able to see your error while typing out your code.

Comment: netBeans is required for the class. I cant use anything else except it.

Comment: That's odd. I've never had a teacher force us to use one specific IDE

Comment: Yeah my professor is very specific and doesnt allow us to use different programming techniques or IDE's. Not a very nice guy.